# Change all columns in table of a certain data type in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

It seems like several months ago I came across a SO question covering this but I can't seem to find it now.

Basically, I want to do two things.

First, a number of tables were made with several columns `numeric(20,2)` and I want to just change them all to `numeric`. The statement is simple enough for one column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN code
TYPE numeric;
```

Takes care of that.

Second, on these columns I want to remove any trailing zeros:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET code = replace(replace(code::text, '.50', '.5'), '.00', '')::numeric;
```

Having difficulty figuring out how to automate it so I only have to specify the table and it will clean up the table. Pretty sure this is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find all of the columns with the data type that you want to change with a statement like:

```
select column_name, table_name
from information_schema.columns
where data_type='numeric'
    and numeric_precision = 20
    and numeric_scale = 2;
```

You can iterate over the result with a custom function or with a DO command such as:

```
do $$
declare
t record;
begin
    for t IN select column_name, table_name
            from information_schema.columns
            where data_type='numeric'
                and numeric_precision = 20
                and numeric_scale = 2;
    loop
        execute 'alter table ' || t.table_name || ' alter column ' || t.column_name || ' type numeric';
    end loop;
end$$;
```

Also, to remove trailing zeroes, a more general solution is to cast the value to float or double precision and then back to numeric, e.g:

```
set code = cast(cast(code as double precision) as numeric);
```

Comment: `select cast('1234.50' as numeric);` will be displayed with a trailing zero, whereas `select cast(cast(cast('1234.50' as numeric) as double precision) as numeric);` will be displayed without a trailing zero.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Honestly it is surprise for me that the `numeric` type holds the initial precision for each value individually. Thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: This worked for the most part. I did have to add `DECLARE t RECORD;` at the beginning to get it working. You saved me a ton of time!