# Altering data types of all columns in a table (PostgreSQL 13)

Tags: database, postgresql, sqldatatypes, alter-table, alter-column

I have a table `import.hugo` (import is schema) and I need to change all columns data type from `text` to `numeric`. The table already has data, so to alter column (for example) `y` I use this:

```
ALTER TABLE import.hugo ALTER COLUMN y TYPE numeric USING (y::numeric);
```

But the table has many columns and I don´t want to do it manually.
I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46308087) and try it like this:

```
do $$
declare
t record;
begin
    for t IN select column_name, table_name
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name='hugo' AND data_type='text'         
    loop
        execute 'alter table ' || t.table_name || ' alter column ' || t.column_name || ' type numeric';
    end loop;
end$$;
```

When I run it, it doesn't work, it says: `relation "hugo" does not exist`
I tried many many more variants of this code, but I can't make it work.
I also don't know, how to implement this part: `USING (y::numeric);` (from the very first command) into this command.

Ideally, I need it in a function, where the user can define the name of a table, in which we are changing the columns data type. So function to call like this `SELECT function_name(table_name_to_alter_columns);`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting `table_name` from `information_schema.columns` isn't enough, since the `import` schema is not in your `search path`.  You can add the `import` schema to your `search_path` by appending `import` to whatever shows up in `SHOW search_path`, or you can just add the `table_schema` column to your `DO` block:

```
do $$
declare
t record;
begin
    for t IN select column_name, table_schema || '.' || table_name as full_name
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name='hugo' AND data_type='text'         
    loop
        execute 'alter table ' || t.full || ' alter column ' || t.column_name || ' type numeric USING (' || t.column_name || '::numeric)';
    end loop;
end$$;
```

Comment: You need to add `and table_schema = 'import'` to the where condition. As it currently exists the query will return any table named *hugo* in all schemata, even if you do not have access to the schema.  What happens when another schema has such  a table and 1: you do have authority to do this but doing so is not wanted? 2: you do not have the necessary authority? Also are you sure all such text columns contain only numeric data.